# schema prefixes in postgres , scope of called elements

Tags: postgresql, schema

Will schema-prefixing a stored procedure also limit the scope of all the procedures called inside it to that schema?

Take the following scenerio in consideration:

Say I have a stored procedure `parentProc` that calls proc `childA` `childB` and `childC`. This procedure is available in all schemas `SchemaA`, `public` and `SchemaB` like this:

```
create or replace procedure parentProc(){
  CALL childA;
  CALL childB;
  CALL childC;
}

SchemaA
|_parentProc
|_childA
|_childB
|_ChildC
SchemaB
|_parentProc
|_childA
|_childB
|_ChildC
public
|_parentProc
|_childA
|_childB
|_ChildC
```

the default search path is public, so when I call `dbo.parentProc` will the procedure in the same schema(dbo) be called or from the `public`?

If childA, childB and childC are views instead, what will happen in that scenerio? Will the parentproc being prefixed scope the views to that schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reference one object using the schema, that doesn't change the fact that all unqualified references use the `search_path` to determine the schema. So if you

```
CALL schemaa.parentproc();
```

but `search_path` is `schemab`, the procedure will still call the procedures from `schemab`.

The same holds for views or all other objects, but note that the objects referenced inside a view do not depend on the setting of `search_path` when the view is used, but on the setting of `search_path` when the view was defined. That is because the defining query is parsed at view creation time and stored in parsed form.

Comment: is there a way to see the parsed view?

Comment: Yes, look into `pg_rewrite`.

Comment: `he same holds for views or all other objects, but note that the objects referenced inside a view do not depend on the setting of search_path when the view is used...` this however does seem to have a net effect of calling the view from public if the view inside the proc is not qualified

Comment: Depends on how you defined the view...

Comment: hm... in the case of running migrations for different schema, the view would be scoped to that schema, but, then calling an unprefixed view from a prefixed proc would again try to call the one that's in public

Comment: Yes. The objects referenced in a view are never influenced by your current `search_path`. The resolution is done when the view is defined.

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-STATEMENT):

> search_path (string) This variable specifies the order in which
> schemas are searched when an object (table, data type, function, etc.)
> is referenced by a simple name with no schema specified. When there
> are objects of identical names in different schemas, the one found
> first in the search path is used. An object that is not in any of the
> schemas in the search path can only be referenced by specifying its
> containing schema with a qualified (dotted) name.

That means that any call to a procedure without a schema qualification, will only find (or not) the procedure that is in the public schema. Because public is in your default search path.

I always use just public for the default, the rest is using a schema qualification.

Comment: meaning the qualification in the parentProc using `dbo.parentproc` doesn't matter if the the child are not schema qualified explicitly?