# localizing a transaction within a procedure externally

Tags: postgresql, transactions

[With regard to my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73725723/schema-prefixes-in-postgres-scope-of-called-elements/73726103#73726103) , I am trying to avoid schema prefixes by setting `search_paths`, however, I want to limit the scope as much as possible so I'm doing this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  SET LOCAL search_path to mySchema;
  CALL STORED_PROCEDURE();
  UPDATE TABLE MYTABLE1(//SOME CODE);
COMMIT;

CALL STORED_PROCEDURE();
```

Now, the proc has it's own begin, commit statements, so I'm wondering if the procedure will respect it's outer transaction, i.e.

1. Will the `stored_procedure` respect the search_path set by it's parent transaction block?
2. if updating the table fails, will operations done inside the procedure also rollback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BEGIN` and `END` in a PL/pgSQL procedure has no connection with the transaction commands `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`/`END`. They just mark a block.

The procedure will use your `search_path`, unless you override that inside your procedure.  A `COMMIT` inside the procedure could require special consideration, but that is not a problem here, since you are not allowed to `COMMIT` inside a procedure that is called from a multi-statement transaction anyway.

Comment: `you are not allowed to COMMIT inside a procedure that is called from a multi-statement transaction anyway` meaning any commit inside the stored proc is ignored if it is wrapped by an outer transaction like above?

Comment: I've also added a scenerio above, what search_path will be used in the second call to the stored proc above? It should persist only inside the outer transaction right?

Comment: If your procedure tries to `COMMIT` you will get an error. And yes, `SET LOCAL` only changes the setting for the transaction.

Comment: I wonder if you could take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73725723/schema-prefixes-in-postgres-scope-of-called-elements , would schema prefix of parent proc scope the child proc/views?